# Waiting for all nodeJS request to be finished and add a small delay to them

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

I have an application that is meant to interact with a remote API.
I have to make around 10000 (10k) requests without having it be too fast that anti-ddos protection will block me. Means I need to add a small delay.

**Code**

```
 var promises = [];
 for(var i = 0 ; i < list.length;i++)
 {
  console.log("checking " + list[i]);
  promises.push(doRequest(token,Username));
 }

 Promise.all(promises).then(function()
 {
  console.log("done");
 },function(err){
  console.log("oops");
 });
```

**doRequest** looks like this:

```
function doRequest(token,username)
{
  var checkUsername = { method: 'GET',
  url: link + username,
  headers: 
   { AUTHORIZATION: 'Bearer ' + token,
     Accept: 'application/json' } };
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) 
    {
      request(checkUsername , function (error, res, body) {
        try
        {
          var json = JSON.parse(body);
          if(json.success)
          {
            resolve(username);
          }
          else
          {
            reject(username);
          }
        }
        catch(exception)
        {
          console.log(body);
          reject(exception);
        }
      });
    });
}
```

It seems that every single time I get to the JSON.parse(body), it crashes because I'm sending request way too fast for the remote server to not consider me to be a spam bot, resulting in my body simply being undefined or simply the code runs too fast resulting in the same thing.

How could I redeem this situation whilst still keeping the asynchronous nature of my code so it's still relatively fast?

Comment: a. https://www.npmjs.com/package/delayed-request, b.https://www.npmjs.com/package/delay, c. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717419/delay-in-a-for-loop-for-http-request

Comment: Checkout the `concurrency` option in https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-all and [Bluebird's Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)

Comment: Async (https://github.com/caolan/async) has some great utility functions, parallelLimit (https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallelLimit) is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on how fast you want to try and make it. How many requests you are allowed to do simultaneously, etc. Here is a possible strategy. The way you want to think about this, is figure out how many concurrent requests you are allowed to make, and break the work up into synchronous blocks that all run concurrently.

```
// the number of simultaneous requests that wont cause problems
const allowedSimultaneous = 10

// create each chain
const chains = Array(allowedSimultaneous).fill(Promise.resolve())

// now build a synchronous list for each block
list.forEach((item, i) => {
  const chainIndex = i % allowedSimultaneous
  chains[chainIndex] = chains[chainIndex]
    .then(() => doRequest(token, Username))
})

// finally use .all() to catch when all chains are completed
Promise.all(chains).then(() => console.log('done'))
```

Note: This is untested code, but hopefully you get the idea. You want to build an amount of concurrent chains, each running a synchronous set of calls. This ensures that the number of concurrent requests will always be `allowedSimultaneous`.

No need for delays at all, as there will only ever be `allowedSimultaneous` calls running, but if you did need some sort of delay, you could just delay after each `doRequest`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of Node that is recent enough for `async/await` this is pretty painless. You can break your requests into groups, await each group, pause (by awaiting a timeout), and continue. For example:

```js
function getGroups(start, end, list) {
  var promises = [];
  end = end > list.length ? list.length : end
  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    console.log("checking " + list[i]);
    promises.push(doRequest(i));
  }
  return Promise.all(promises)
}

function doRequest(i) {
  // fake request
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(i), 750))
}


async function get(list) {
  const group_size = 5
  const wait_time = 1500
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i += group_size) {
    console.log("getting group")
    let group_result = await (getGroups(i, i + group_size, list))
    console.log("results of group: ", group_result)
    console.log("Waiting")
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, wait_time))

  }
}
let urls = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
get(urls)
```

If you just want to put a small delay between *each* request, you can use `async/await` in a loop with something like:

```js
function doRequest(i) {
  /* fake request */
  console.log("requesting: ", i)
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(i), 250))
}

let urls = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

async function get() {
  let results = []
  for (url of urls) {
    results.push(await doRequest(url))
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200))
  }
  return results
}
get().then(r => console.log("results: ", r))
```

Of course, you'll want to do error checking, etc...

Comment: This way works (and should be fine for most cases), but the block and wait method doesn't keep the most efficient flow of calls possible. For example if your block is size 5, and one of the calls hangs for some reason, there is a period of not doing much. The larger the block, the more this effect is seen.

Answer (score 0):

NPM has a couple of packages for throttling promises. This one is the top:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-throttle